# Create a wildcard DNS entry in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008

I'm using R2 and I managed to get the forward and reverse lookup zones working so that for my domain "foo.lab" I can create entries like

```
abc.foo.lab   192.168.1.10
def.foo.lab   192.168.1.10
```

How can I create an entry so that anything NOT defined will always point to a specific ip address?

eg. if someone tries to resolve ghi.foo.lab it will resolve to 192.168.10.10 (or whatever ip I want)

Answer (score 6):

Add a new (A) entry in forward lookup zone and for the name put *